# Send data between 2 controllers MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My problem: I have a list A selected from database of a controller A, controller A will display list A. In view, each record of list A has a link call controller B (`@html.ActionLink("text","actionB","controllerB", new {id=listA.ID})`) and i want to send list A to controller B as well. I've searched about how can send data between 2 controller, there are 2 ways are:

1. Using tempdata
2. Using session

But all of those above is not really suitable on this case, can anyone tell me other ways to solve my problems. Thanks

Comment: why not retrieve the list again in controller B? sending data between 2 controllers is kind of a pain. You can't send objects, only primitives (if you want to call a method of controller B)

Comment: doesnt sound like you're trying to send data from controller to controller.. sounds like you want controller to view to controller

Comment: @AbdulAhmad is it a good way to select list again from database on controller B? I'm total new with web development, i think i can save memory when i tranfer list from controller A => controller B instead of selecting data again?

Comment: @JanmieD77 Do you have any suggestion for this problem

Comment: Getting a new select list will surely be cheaper than serializing something to the view and then deserializing it back in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative would be to retrieve the list again in your second controller. This is generally pretty cheap and fast.

Comment: but we have to access database again, is it faster ?

Comment: I don't think there will be a noticeable speed difference either way

Comment: so in common, people will select data again, right? can you explain the reason why its cheap and fast?

Comment: Yea people will generally retrieve the data again. I can't answer why its faster because I don't know. You can google that to learn more.

Comment: This is cheap but certainly not fast! 2 DB requests are made for no reason. Why not pass the list to your controller..

Comment: @TranDuyLinh you can post the same list back to controller B. Partial Views may also help with your controller consolidation and presentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do. For things like lists I may re-use in several places I utilise the `Initialize` method in each controller then check the `Action` name to determine which lists of objects I need to load.

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
     base.Initialize(requestContext);

     //if this is the insert or edit form - get the lists for the  d.down form inputs
    var actionName = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().ToLower();
    if (actionName == "insert" || actionName == "edit")
    {
        var _uow = new UnitOfWork();

        var lstMyList = _uow.MyRepository.Get().OrderBy(n => n.title).ToList();

        _uow.Dispose();

        ViewBag.MyList = lstMyList;
    }
}
```

Obviously the code to retrieve the list may differ depending on how you access your DB but you get the idea. This way, you only call in one place within each controller's code and yes, it may result in more database calls but for me, I like the neatness of not having calls littered all through my actions. `MyList` is available in the `ViewBag` to populate form controls or output where needed or for in-view logic if you're that way inclined.

Answer (score 0):

As the application grows there will be many requests you will need to make requests to the db, do not worry about such calls to the db.

However to answer your question...

1. You can store it in session/tempdata and then retrieve it. This will increase your server memory usage, what if the user didnt have to look at the detail. It's just a waste.
2. You store it in the page it self as json and then post it to the server and pass it to the second controller, but the data can be manipulated on client and also increases the bandwidth, making the page slower to download and upload.
3. Becomes difficult to maintain.

In short retrieve it from db from the second controller.